# Is it possible to run a Knapsack 0-1 problem in Python with product couples?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, knapsack-problem, gurobi

I have created an integer program in Python with GurobiPy for the 0-1 knapsack problem. However, I want to add a constraint that sais that if product x is added, then product y must also be added for some product couples.

My current model:
There are 2 warehouses, if products are stored in the main warehouse, the profit loss (due to delays) is 0. If the products are stored in the new warehouse, the profit loss is as presented in the dataframe. The objective is to minimize the profit loss

```
# Note: I run the program for the second warehouse because Xi returns values of 1 if placed in the warehouse
# so I can calculate the profit loss easier by just multiplying Xi by the profit loss

c = 1720 # total number of boxes minus capacity of the main warehouse
p = dfGurobi['profit'].tolist() # profit of each product
w = dfGurobi['boxes_required'].tolist() # weight of each product (=number of boxes required)
l = dfGurobi['profitLoss'].tolist() # profit loss of each product

n = len(p) # so determine the number of variables
assert n == len(w) # lengths of p and w should be the same
model = Model() # create a model

x = model.addVars(n, vtype=GRB.BINARY) # add variables
model.setObjective(quicksum(l[i] * x[i] for i in range(n)), GRB.MINIMIZE) # set objective to minimize the profit loss generated by placing products in the new warehouse
model.addConstr(quicksum(w[i] * x[i] for i in range(n)) >= c) # set constraint that the number of boxes in the new warehouse is at least 1720 so that the number of boxes in the main warehouse is at most 960
result = model.optimize() # optimize the model
print(result)
print("The optimal total profit loss is: %g" % model.objVal)

print(dfGurobi)
```

Also, I have a list of product couples indicating that if product 1 is placed in the main op new warehouse, the second product must also be placed in the same warehouse. This is the list:

```
          product2
product1          
74              45
74             328
74             367
74             535
74             642
74             802
191            356
191            931
328            929
362            535
367            929
382            587
382            823
382            828
535            665
535           1223
574            931
642           1223
685            535
685            671
685            828
685            845
685            921
685           1030
823            931
828            747
828            931
845            592
1136           191
1136           587
1136           823
1136           828
1136           845
```

Background info:

my Pandas Dataframe looks like this;

```
          profitLoss      profit  boxes_required
product_id                                        
571          96.849644  484.248219             1.0
533          96.358619  481.793096             1.0
831          89.424493  447.122466             1.0
276          77.455923  387.279616             1.0
162          76.336142  381.680712             1.0
...                ...         ...             ...
337           0.478582    0.957163             1.0
840           0.468519    0.937037             1.0
433           0.385460    0.770919             1.0
384           0.305156    0.610311             1.0
361           0.274544    0.549088             1.0

[1263 rows x 3 columns]
```

How can I best add the product couples as a constraint?
Edit:
My specific problem is: If product 1 is added to the warehouse (i.e. has a value of Xi = 1), then product 2 must also be added (i.e. have a value of Xi = 1). How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My specific problem is: I want to add product 2 to the warehouse if product 1 is added but I don't know how to do this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling belongs in or.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

A basic precedence constraint can look like:

```
 x[j] >= x[i]
```

which means `if x[i]=1 then x[j]=1`

Comment: That is obviously not correct. We can all agree that (1) GurobiPy allows you to specify linear constraints and that (2) this is a  linear constraint.

Comment: You are mistaken. `(i,j)` form a product couple here, e.g. `i=74, j=45`.

Answer (score -1):

I already solved it myself
To ensure that the product couples are both assigned to the same warehouse you can use the addGenConstrIndicator from gurobi. For me the solution looked like this:

```py
for i in couplesList1:
   for j in couplesList2:
        model.addGenConstrIndicator(x[i], True, x[j], GRB.EQUAL, 1,0
```

Which basically sais that if x[i] is 1 then x[j] should also be 1
The couplesList1 and couplesList2 contain the product pairs (product 1 and product 2)

Comment: Very roundabout (also known as unreadable i.e. bad) way for expressing `x[j] >= x[i]`. BTW the indicator constraint can be written in a much more readable form using the `>>` operator.